# Read text in a WebSite in Visual Studio VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I tried so much to read a text in a website, but nothing worked. I just want to get the text in [this webpage](https://pptgamespt.wixsite.com/crate-database) but I can't find out the correct code.

Here's the last code I tried:

```
MsgBox(WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("body").InnerHtml.ToString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this by replacing with your URL:

Call below line of code to navigate the webpage.

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("file:///C:/Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/test/test.html")
```

Handle `DocumentCompleted` (basically asynchronous). If you do not handle in this event, you may end up in accessing the content before page is downloaded.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        MessageBox.Show(WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml)
End Sub
```

In the above code you can also use `Document.GetElementById("body").InnerHtml` if you know that the body tag is like `<BODY id='body'>` . When you are not sure of **id**, it is better to go with `Document.Body.InnerHtml`

***Note: Probably for your case, it is good to use webrequest classes. Refer below link***.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-request-data-using-the-webrequest-class

or if your project demands more of this situations, using `HtmlAgilityPack` is also not a bad idea.